# how to get value of 'value' attribute of a disabled input

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to get the value 'Accept' using webdriver. But I always get blank. I tried all `By` options such as `id`, `name`, `xpath` etc.

```
<input type="submit" value="Accept" id="nid" name="n" class="c" disabled="disabled">
```

Webdriver

```
WebElement aButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@name='n']"));
System.out.println(aButton.getText());                #=> blank
System.out.println(aButton.getAttribute("value"));    #=> blank
```

Comment: Try to execute javascript

    `$$('#nid').attr('value');`

This should do the thing.

Answer (score -1):

Selenium docs clearly saying about `gettext()` is:

> *Get the visible (i.e. not hidden by CSS) innerText of this element, including sub-elements, without any leading or trailing whitespace*

So you could not directly use it but you could try the `executeScript` method of WebDriver, Write some js script that fetch the hidden element value and execute that script using this method. It could help.

Comment: `disabled` is different from `hidden`

Comment: @Bala - I tested on a small app with the html element provided by you and I can able to get the value of that element using below code       WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.id("nid"));
System.out.println(e.getAttribute("value")); I could also able to get the value using By.xpath("//*[@name='n']") and By.xpath("//*[@id='nid']") ... You defiantly have some other issue. Kindly check your code.